# Why when I add my NAV bar does it move my H1 element?

Tags: html, css

I've tried adding a nav bar, but as soon as I add the nav bar it instantly moves my H1 element over to the right, or left, depending on where I place my nav bar in the DOM tree. If I add padding to the H1 to fix the centring issue, it then breaks all my responsive design as the browser get's smaller. Surely their's a fix?

```
<body>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="name">
    <h2 class="myname">Lee Howard</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<header id="header">
  <nav class="main-nav">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#about">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact-info">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
 </nav>
  <h1 class="title">Front end developer.
    <br>
    <span>WORKING HARD TO BECOME GREAT</span>
    </h1>
</header>

 #header {
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 960px;
 width: 100%;
 background: url(../img/header.jpg)
          no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}


#header h1 {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif, font-weight: 400;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 0.8em;
font-size: 4.25em;
}

#header h1 span {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
color: #363636;
font-size: 0.30em;
}


#name {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
margin-right: -80px;
right: 51%;
}


/****************************
 NAVIGATION
******************************/

.main-nav {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.main-nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 }

.main-nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: everything takes up room, you haven't said what layout you want, and you need to learn about css box model and positioning, width, height, display.

Comment: Sorry. I already have my layout set (leezzki.github.io) is my website. All I want is just a nav bar inline with my name at the top. If I have to re position and fix my breakpoints then I will. I'm just sure their's a more simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because your header has

```
display:table
```

and h1 has

```
display:table-cell
```

You have `position:absolute` on your `#name` that removes the width of the element as well.

I've made a few amends and if works here.
https://jsfiddle.net/t3s2ht8n/